# FabricJS How to make exact Circle Boundary

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to create exact Circle Boundary in order to create drag & drop quiz. By dragging and dropping the red circle to purple or blue circle or both areas as shown in the image below:

[The quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7L4n.png)

The problem is the purple or blue circle has rectangle boundary when I used red circle to drag and drop and detect that within circle area by `isContainedWithinObject` function, as shown below:

[The rectangle boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Lwj.png)

How to create exact circle boundary like this:

[The exact boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eVIi.png)

Comment: If you know the coordinates of the center of each circle, you can compute distance between from the mouse to the center of each circle, and when that distance is less than the radius, you can activate dropping for that circle.

Comment: This is a non-answer but if you can draw the circles as SVGs, then you can set the pointer event to fire when you enter the circles, all using DOM events API. It might be easier than html-canvas.

Comment: I see, so you give me another approach to solve the problem. Thanks anyway for your proposed approach. I will make your idea as an another option. @evenstar